# Azure Web App with Acitve Directory Express with Graph API to get user photo

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My Azure Web App has Active Directory enabled using the Express option. I can get the user claims/user's name from auth.me. How do I then get the user's photo/avatar?  The token I get is not working in a Graph API call.  I get this error from Graph API.  Here is my code.

Please help!  Spent hours searching and reading docs but nothing seems to address the Express AD scenario.
Thanks
Donnie

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "e25f1fe5-4ede-4966-93c2-6d92d34da6ae",
  "date": "2019-03-13T14:13:26"
}
}
}

axios.get('/.auth/me').then(resp => {

      if(resp.data){
           loggedInUser = {
            accessToken:resp.data[0].access_token,
            userId: resp.data[0].user_id,
            username: resp.data[0].user_claims[9].val,
            lastname: resp.data[0].user_claims[8].val,
            fullname: resp.data[0].user_claims[11].val,
            avatar:'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg'
          } 
          let config = {
            'headers':{
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + loggedInUser.accessToken
            }
          }

           axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value',config).then(resp => {
            let photo = resp.data;
            const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(photo);
            document.getElementById('avatar').setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
            loggedInUser.avatar = blobUrl;
            console.log(blobUrl)
          }); 
      }
      })
```

Comment: how did you go about setting up your Azure AD? I'm wondering if you need to use login.microsoftonline.com rather than /.auth/me under your webapp.

Comment: I just enabled active directory for an azure web app. AD works fine for login. I get the token.  Issue is with graph call.

Comment: And you added the Microsoft delegate permissions to your AD app registration?

Comment: Don’t know what that means or how to do it? Please provide more details? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pull the image using MSDAL to handle the token. The new App Registration blade (as of 4/10/2019 is in preview) has a quick start which will ensure your app registration is correctly configure and allow you to download sample code.

[image: App Registration]

In this blade, make sure you've added graph API permissions as shown below. When you click on Quick Start, you'll get a sample similar to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/RyanHill-MSFT/c9d697574fb8faff45a57e1c6c39ffd2). It makes use of MSAL js library which handles the token negotiation.

```
    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority,
        acquireTokenRedirectCallBack, {
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
            cacheLocation: "localStorage"
        });

    function signIn() {
        myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
            //Login Success
            showWelcomeMessage();
            acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

After that, the magic happens in

```
acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph()
```

which will acquire the token so you can use it to call the graph API. Now my [gist](https://gist.github.com/RyanHill-MSFT/c9d697574fb8faff45a57e1c6c39ffd2) makes use of XMLHttpRequest which I'm sure you'll be able to replace with axios.

Comment: Yes. Express will create the registration. All you have to do is open the Azure Active Directory blade, select App Registrations and your AD Express registration will be listed.

Comment: Thank you Ryan!  This looks comprehensive.  Thanks for the gist!  My only question is why this requires the user to click login button vs. the auto-redirect express currently does?

Comment: There might be an available API method in the MSAL js library that would allow you to hook into the express authentication, I'm just not that familiar with the library. But if there were a limitation, I'd point my finger to the required scopes that has to be sent when getting the token with the necessary authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To get the photo in the v1.0, it supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

[image]

For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: Thank you. This is the doc I used to write the attached code. However, I still get the error.  My question is, does it work with token from AzureAD Express in Azure Web App. Mine is a company mailbox.

Comment: Could you share your code to request the token? There may be something wrong with your request?

Answer (score 0):

Your AD app registration may not have the necessary delegate [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions). To add those permissions to your app, see [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis) steps. I think you may need to use the oauth (login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/v2.0/token) endpoint rather than .auth/me. With the oauth endpoint, you can even elect to pass in the [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent) your token needs for calling the graph API. You can use http://jwt.ms to [decode](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-8-authentication-roadmap-and-access-tokens/#) the token and see if has the necessary delegate permissions.

Also, I came across this [blog series](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/announcing-30-days-of-microsoft-graph-blog-series/#) that lists various tutorials for working the Microsoft Graph. You can also check out https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample.

Furthermore, https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample makes use of passport and passport-azure-ad npm packages. That actually may be more advantagous to getting and managing tokens from Azure AD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this endpoint instead of auth/me, https://login.microsoftonline.com/BelmontTechnology/oauth2/v2.0/token' , but I get CORS blocked.

Comment: Extremely frustrating!  There are so many confusing ways to do this.  I simply want the pass the auth/me token I get, per the Azure Web App instructions, and pass that to get the user's photo!

Comment: I get the frustration and there is light at the end of tunnel. Did http://jwt.ms help in decoding the token you get from .auth/me? Were you able to add the additional delegate permissions to your App AD registration?

Comment: I did add permissions. See screenshot other reply.  I didn’t try jwt yet. Will try it

Comment: any idea why the token doesn’t work in jwt.ms?  See screenshot I posted

Comment: I don't know why this would fail for you. I'm trying to do a similar app and see if I run into same issues.

Comment: Have Any luck Ryan?

Comment: Hi Donnie, to get the token try login.microsoftonline.com/belmonttechnology.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token instead. That might have been the CORS issue as the tenant name wasn't complete. You can also replace that tenant name with your directory ID that you'll find on the Active Directory blade, Properties section. Let me know if that works. 
 In the meantime, I'm still trying to get a working sample.

Comment: I ran into similar issues with using the token provided by login.microsoftonline.com. My token was successfully decoded by jwt.ms but it wasn't authorized for graph rest api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/intune-graph-apis#register-apps-to-use-the-microsoft-graph-api makes use of passport npm packages that "should" work but have been running to issues myself.

Comment: Ryan, Any progress on this?

Comment: Sorry Donnie, I was out for the past week. But we'll definitely get this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, I added delegate permissions to my web app's permissions settings for reading user profiles, but I still get the error message when tying to get profile pic from graph.  Not sure what permissions it needs, but I basically gave it full access to use's profile.  Graph just doesn't seem to like the token provided by AD Express config (login.microsoftonline.com)

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "e25f1fe5-4ede-4966-93c2-6d92d34da6ae",
"date": "2019-03-13T14:13:26"
}
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, jwt fails when I paste the full token from auth/me .
[image]